# Is there any way to merge visual studio silverlight windows phone into visual studio windows phone apache cordova

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

We are developing a mobile application, We had finished 3 out of 10 modules in visual studio windows phone(silverlight) , But suddenly for some reason we have to build a hybrid application in(visual studio apache cordova), How to I merge or convert a older one(developed in visual studio silverlight) into new development tool visual studio 2013 community (Apache Cordova).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Cordova is based on HTML, CSS and JS and unfortunately silverlight project cannot be converted into Cordova app.

Comment: Is there any performance issue on developing apache cordova app.